# How to set up a bigger canvas size in Android

Tags: android, image, android-canvas

I'm drawing a image that goes from x=0 to the end of the screen and beyond. I would like the screen to move to follow the image for at least 3 screen widhts. How can this be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Simon, can you help me with this?